# Code Igniter communication and data exchange between two applications

Tags: codeigniter

I have two server alpha and beta both are development server basic idea is alpha server should acknowledged to beta and beta server should then start downloading files from alpha to beta.
I have to do it using codeigniter, php. How should I proceed to start developing application?

Answer (score 0):

So, to clarify, you are storing data on alpha that you want beta to pull on a regular basis - is this correct?

If so, do you want this to be automated or manually done by the user? If you want it to be automated you can call CoedIgniter controllers via the system's crontab using the [CodeIgniter CLI](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html). I do this all the time to run nightly cleanup and bulk-processing jobs.

Are you looking to pull actual files or just raw data?

Comment: I want to pull actual file which alpha will create it in zip file format